# How does MXNET C++ code bind with its python API?

Tags: python, deep-learning, mxnet, custom-operator

1.When defining custom operator in MXNet with C++, how does the custom operator defined in C++ generate its python API automatically? 
2.How can I finde the corresponding codes?
3. What's the difference between defining custom operator with C++ and with python?

Answer (score 2):

The macro NNVM_REGISTER_OP registers an operator by name that is then visible from python. From there, you define attributes of the operator (ie FCompute, which is the function to call when invoked).

In the C++ section here, there is a guide:  https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/how_to/new_op.html